# Android Espresso MockWebserver setting cookies

Tags: android, android-espresso, mockwebserver

I tried to set cookies in my Android Instrumentationtest like this:

```
  @Override
protected MockResponse onDispatch(RecordedRequest request) {
    if (request.getPath().startsWith("/?loginkulcs=")) {
        MockResponse response = new MockResponse()
                .setStatus(new BasicStatusLine(new ProtocolVersion("HTTP",1,1), 302, "Moved Temporarily").toString())
                .setHeaders(new Headers.Builder()
                        .add("Date", LocalDateTime.now().toString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"))
                        .add("Server", "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2")
                        .add("X-Powered-By", "Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)")
                        .add("Location","https://xxx.jsp")
                        .add("Content-Type","text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1")
                        .add("Content-Language","en-US")
                        .add("Content-Length","227")
                        .add("Keep-Alive","timeout=5, max=100")
                        .add("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
                        .add("Set-Cookie", String.format("session_id=%s; Path=/xxx_teszt/", SESSION_ID))
                        .add("Set-Cookie", "regisztralt=IGEN; Path=/xxx_teszt/")
                        .add("Set-Cookie", "session_id=2084e74283d5073c5f4d324f17e2; Path=/xxx_teszt; HttpOnly")
                        .build());
        return response;
    }
    return null;

}
```

the android client is an org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient and it reads cookies like this:

client.getCookieStore().getCookies();

But the result is null. 
How can I set the cookies for this client?

thx

Zamek

Answer (score 0):

it is `Cookie` and not `Set-Cookie`; see the [MockWebServerTest](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/mockwebserver/src/test/java/okhttp3/mockwebserver/MockWebServerTest.java), for example:

```
.addHeader("Cookie: " + String.format("session_id=%s; Path=/xxx_teszt/", SESSION_ID))
```

Comment: Sorry the original is working like this, there is a sessionId by a cookie, when the I get an 302 code. I don't know does it conform with standard or doesn't, but I have to do it.

Comment: @zamekz you'd have to fix the headers on the server-side, and then fix the mock of it. the page after the `302`, which then sends `200` should set the cookie headers. or just run one test, which tests the `302` redirect and another one, which tests the redirect destination, which should send a `200`.

Comment: I tried to set return code 200 instead of 302, but the cookies are empty:(

Comment: @zamekz it it actually setting any headers?

Comment: I use only http. It is working in a live webserver, I just want to create a test case for this, because I cannot generate test data on the live webserver. The live webserver working with these data, I simply copy the header data from a live data. The live webserver sends three different cookies, I think so cookies should be a map which contains list as a value.

Comment: @zamekz just have found the mistake (which I've suspected) and updated my answer... please accept, because the URL of the tests for the mock-webserver, should reliably answer the question.

Comment: I checked the stored values after I create it, and everything seems to be good, except that, every key converted to small letter:
 key:cookie
      value:regisztralt=IGEN; Path=/enaplo_teszt/
      value:session_id=32a53dc792a605b87d6ea75415be8e48; Path=/enaplo_teszt/

Comment: @zamekz does the same happen with the live web-server? it's not really clear if cookie names are indeed case-sensitive, whether or not... there are 3 RFC, which obsolete each other. some state they are, other say, that aren't. here in this case it only matters how the cookies of the live web-server are being handled.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, because I wanted to print all headers after I added to response. I could get it with toMultiMap() which is convert all header keys to lowercase. But the sent headers was correct, not converted.

Comment: I found the problem! The client rejected the cookie because:
"illegal path attribute" Path of origin"/ message. In test I don't need to use these Path property. I removed it and it works well. 
Thank you for your help.